# Can I do an unless query in SQL? Using row_num query

Tags: sql-server

I am running a query to keep the last submitted record based on mobile. I have that process nailed down, as you can see in the below query example.

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT 
   mobile,
   submission_date, 
   source,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY mobile
      ORDER BY mobile, submission_date DESC
   ) row_num
FROM 
   table
    )
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE row_num > 1
```

I want to adapt this query to fulfil this new need. Here is some example data.

| id | mobile | submission_date | source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0400000000 | 06-06-2020 | AAAA |
| 2 | 0400000000 | 05-05-2020 | BBBB |
| 3 | 0411111111 | 09-09-2020 | BBBB |
| 4 | 0411111111 | 08-08-2020 | BBBB |
| 5 | 0422222222 | 08-08-2020 | AAAA |

I want to be able to only delete row 1 if the source = AAAA, UNLESS row 2 does not exist.

I want to be able to also say something along the lines of

```
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE row_num = 1 AND source in ('AAAA')
UNLESS row 2 does not exist
```

This would allow me to keep record 5 even though it is row 1 and source AAAA, because there is no 2nd record with the same mobile number. In other words, record 1 would be the only record to be deleted using the example data.

Comment: thats usually implementing using `exists` i.e. `delete where exists ()`

Comment: ```DELETE FROM cte
WHERE row_num = 1 AND source in ('AAAA') 
AND row 2 exists```
But how would that actually be written in the query?

Comment: `exists` takes a sub-query, there are loads of examples online.

Comment: Put `LEAD()` into the CTE, then you can see if there is another row within the outer `DELETE`, without having to subquery `EXISTS`